# React Native Lottie Splash Screen in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, lottie

We are trying to use a Lottie file on the Splash Screen of an iOS React Native project. We are trying to use [react-native-lottie-splash-screen](https://github.com/HwangTaehyun/react-native-lottie-splash-screen) but instructions on how to add the Lottie file to Xcode are minimal.

After installing react-native-lottie-splash-screen, I'm wondering how we place the Lottie file into Xcode to show in the app splash screen?

Note: there are few tickets asking roughly the same question but are sparse on the details when describing how to deal with the Xcode part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Coulde you see this issue in react-native-lottie-splash-screen repo?
It seems same question. (https://github.com/HwangTaehyun/react-native-lottie-splash-screen/issues/25)

You simply drag your lottie file in Xcode's file explorer (left side) and lottie file's name should be loding.json.

Thank you!